# Can I change the configurations in FireFox webextension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to build a Firefox extension that will need to change the configurations (about:config). It is not obvious whether I can change the configurations (about:config) in webextension? 
If not, is there any way to do this in the old development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the webextensions FAQ (the answer is no):
https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/FAQ#Will_I_have_access_to_about:config_or_the_preferences.3F

I'm not sure about your second question, if you're asking about the add-on SDK, it has a module for accessing preferences but extensions written with the SDK will stop working in Firefox 57:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service